# imap dont show all folders

Tags: php, imap, inbox

I work on a webmail with imap,
I connet to imap with :

```
   $IMAPHostname = "localhost";
    $IMAPPort = "143";
    $IMAPFlags = "/novalidate-cert";
```

I connet with

```
$Folder="INBOX.Drafts";

$Mailbox ='{'.$IMAPHostname.":".$IMAPPort.$IMAPFlags.'}'.$Folder;
$imap = imap_open ($Mailbox, $session->username."@mydomain.com", $session->password);
```

I get list folder by :

```
$list = imap_list($mailbox, "{imap.mydomain.com}", "*");
```

Output :

```
"pass","INBOX.Drafts","INBOX.Trash","INBOX.spam","INBOX.Sent","errors reports","Spam","INBOX"
```

when I try :

```
imap_append($imap, "INBOX.Drafts", $mail->getSentMIMEMessage(), "\\Seen");
```

show this error :

> "Can't append to mailbox INBOX.Drafts: no such mailbox"

when I get count message in draft return 2 mails.
what's wrong?